Gemini API Error 400: Invalid or Unsupported File URI
I am trying to build an Android app using a no-code platform but there are certain features that the platform doesn't offer.
I want to prompt Gemini with an Image file using the API. I have created an HTML page that will be embedded into the Android app however I am facing too many issues when prompting Gemini with the image.
<!DOCTYPE html>

    Gemini API Image Upload
    
    
    <h1>Upload Image URL to Gemini API</h1>
    
    <input type="text" id="imageUrlInput" placeholder="Enter public image URL">
    <button id="uploadButton">Submit</button>
    
    
    <div id="responseArea"></div>
    
    <script>
        
        const apiKey = 'api key is here';
    
       
        const imageUrlInput = document.getElementById('imageUrlInput');
        const uploadButton = document.getElementById('uploadButton');
        const responseArea = document.getElementById('responseArea');
    
        
        async function sendImageToGemini(imageUrl) {
            const apiUrl = `https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/gemini-1.5-pro-latest:generateContent?key=${apiKey}`;
    
            
            const payload = {
                "contents": [
                    {
                        "role": "user",
                        "parts": [
                            {
                                "fileData": {
                                    "fileUri": imageUrl,
                                    "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "text": "Please solve this mathematics question"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "generationConfig": {
                    "temperature": 1,
                    "topK": 64,
                    "topP": 0.95,
                    "maxOutputTokens": 8192,
                    "responseMimeType": "text/plain"
                }
            };
    
            try {
                const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(payload)
                });
    
                const data = await response.json();
                responseArea.innerHTML = `<h3>Response:</h3><pre>${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>`;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                responseArea.innerHTML = `<h3>Error:</h3><pre>${error}</pre>`;
            }
        }
    
        
        uploadButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const imageUrl = imageUrlInput.value;
    
            if (imageUrl) {
                sendImageToGemini(imageUrl);
            } else {
                alert('Please enter a public image URL first.');
            }
        });
    </script>

But the output i am getting is:

{"error": {"code": 400, "message": "Invalid or unsupported file uri: https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKETNAME/IMAGEFILE.jpg", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}

I have already set up google cloud console, enabled billing, set the public URL, etc. This error persists even after doing this.
Tried to prompt Gemini with an Image
Error 400: Invalid file URI

I assume you're able to e.g. curl https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKETNAME/IMAGEFILE.jpg --output foo.jpg successfully?

Curious. Click example request "Shell". This uses inline_data where you must base64 encode the image file content and upload the result. It's curious but FilePart appears to not be usable.

Aha! I think you must first upload files (see example request and "Shell"), get the URI from that method before you can use a URI-generated this way as part of FilePart.

So, either open the file locally, encode the content and generateContent using inlineData; or upload the file to Gemini, get a URI and then generateContent using fileData. The documentation could be improved.

I got the same error when trying to use supabase storage or random jpg files on the internet instead of Google AI File Manager. It's not clear if only files uploaded to GoogleAIFileManager are the only ones supported. The docs are again not helpful enough. I did find a github issue: "This only supports files in the API. There are currently no plans to expand this.", which is referring to google ai file manager.

The first thing i would do is make sure you have the correct file url.
Files list
If you are not sure you have the corect file url you may want to try
async function filesList() {
  // [START files_list]
  // Make sure to include these imports:
  // import { GoogleAIFileManager } from "@google/generative-ai/server";
  const fileManager = new GoogleAIFileManager(process.env.API_KEY);

  const listFilesResponse = await fileManager.listFiles();

  // View the response.
  for (const file of listFilesResponse.files) {
    console.log(`name: ${file.name} | display name: ${file.displayName}`);
  }
  // [END files_list]
}

If you dont see it then you may want to try and check how you are uploading it to the file api.
async function filesCreateImage() {
  // [START files_create_image]
  // Make sure to include these imports:
  // import { GoogleAIFileManager } from "@google/generative-ai/server";
  // import { GoogleGenerativeAI } from "@google/generative-ai";
  const fileManager = new GoogleAIFileManager(process.env.API_KEY);

  const uploadResult = await fileManager.uploadFile(
    `${mediaPath}/jetpack.jpg`,
    {
      mimeType: "image/jpeg",
      displayName: "Jetpack drawing",
    },
  );
  // View the response.
  console.log(
    `Uploaded file ${uploadResult.file.displayName} as: ${uploadResult.file.uri}`,
  );

  const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(process.env.API_KEY);
  const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: "gemini-1.5-flash" });
  const result = await model.generateContent([
    "Tell me about this image.",
    {
      fileData: {
        fileUri: uploadResult.file.uri,
        mimeType: uploadResult.file.mimeType,
      },
    },
  ]);
  console.log(result.response.text());
  // [END files_create_image]
}

files.js
